# Get feedback from hibernate after task completion

Tags: java, hibernate, split

I have a little problem where I don't know how to do it right.

I use Hibernate (MySQL) to store (let's so call it) "products" and I have an object called "Identifier".

```
Identifier
----------
Listname    | is the name of a txt,csv.... with 1 up to 1000 products
ProductKey  | is just a little piece of information about the product used    
            | to get more information due to an external API
Processed   | simple 1 or 0 to say the Product information is completed
```

So the table could look like this.

```
"test.txt" | productkey1234 | 1  
"test.txt" | productkey2345 | 1  
"test.txt" | productkey3456 | 1  
"test.txt" | productkey4567 | 0  
"file.txt" | productkey1 | 1  
"file.txt" | productkey2 | 1  
"file.txt" | productkey3 | 1
```

I have a background service that has to check if every product in a list was processed and if so it should get all the products and write a result file with all the complete information about them. (That's not the problem).

But how do I ask Hibernate to check if a so called List is ready if I have 6000 Entries with 10 different lists? (Every product in a list is processed)

Before I used Hibernate, I splitted the query and got myself all the unique lists and ran a loop with each list 
`"SELECT sum(processed) as done,count(processed) as all from Identifier where list = 'listname'"` the if done equals all I knew the list was ready and I could get all the products and delete the Identifier containing the `listname`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the question is: *How to translate this SQL query to HQL?*, then the answer is very simple:

```
SELECT sum(i.processed) as done, count(i.processed) as all 
from Identifier i 
where i.list = 'listname'
```

See the documentation on [aggregate functions in HQL](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-aggregation).

Comment: Hello JB Nizet. Thank. No i was not particually looking for an translation, but this will help too. I wanted to know if there is a smoother way to do it, like using a Criterea. Or if there is a better strategy for doing what I want.

Comment: Hibernate is an ORM. It provides a layer of abstraction over the database. But in the end, seacrhing the database is still done using database queries. Criteria is useful to write dynamic queries. For static queries, HQL is much more readable and should be preferred. Both serve the same purpose: executing database queries.

Comment: Ok, copy that. But in the end my way of selecting the sum and the count is the best way of doing it? I just wanted a single query and not a query where I select all the list names and do another query just for the check.

Comment: Then use `select i.list, sum(i.processed) as done, count(i.processed) as all from Identifier i where i.list in :listNames groub by i.list`.